# Plot legend shows unknown item/ same legend item shown twice with line different style

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am plotting some routes on a black and white png. Now it appears that there is a item in the legend that should not be there. I am iterating a pandas dataframe and identify the different routes by there unique id. I also have a start and a end point that i have right at the beginning of the dataframe, so at `i=0`, and `i=1`, I plot `marker='o'` instead, so I can see that single points on my plot/rows in my dataframe. All working fine so far, but as you can see in the legend for `i=0`, there are 2 entries. Once the `starting point`, but in the second line it adds an orange line. How can that be? In the dataframe it is definitely only 1 row with `id=0`.

Here my code with an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[100,60,1,1,1,5,4,4], 'y':[100,125,1,2,3,10,10,9],'id':[0,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
for i, g in df.groupby('id'):     
    if(i==0):
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax,marker='o',title="Alternative Routes",label="Start Punkt")
    if(i==1):
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax,marker='o',title="Alternative Routes",label="End Punkt")
    else:
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax, title="Alternative Routes",label=i)
plt.show()
```

Here the resulting plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by myself: Should be an `elif` instead of a an `if` for `i==1`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[100,60,1,1,1,5,4,4], 'y':[100,125,1,2,3,10,10,9],'id':[0,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
for i, g in df.groupby('id'):     
    if(i==0):
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax,marker='o',title="Alternative Routes",label="Start Punkt")
    elif(i==1):
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax,marker='o',title="Alternative Routes",label="End Punkt")
    else:
        g.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax, title="Alternative Routes",label=i)
plt.show()
```